# minimize MikTeX for project delivery

Tags: xetex, miktex

I just completed my tex project(compile by `XeLaTeX`) with `MikTeX`, and need to copy the project to others for use/edit. The project is so simple that it just uses some packages.

My question is: the MikTeX is so large and most of it does not help to my project. How can I select only the related files of MikTeX with my project wrap together for delivery?

Comment: you could (it might be easier to use texlive) but have you considered using an online platform such as overleaf so you don't need to distribute tex at all.

Comment: You could look at TinyTeX, which was developed for use with R but it can also be used stand-alone (https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex-releases). See also the [tinytex tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tinytex) here on TeX.SE.

Comment: By default, MiKTeX only installs a the bare minimum of packages (you may not need all of them but they aren't optional for a LaTeX installation) and only downloads others as required when typesetting documents. So it seems that this is already what you want?

Comment: @schtandard Even minimum installation of MiKTeX, only a few of them(engines, fonts, packages etc.) are used for my project. But I don't know what files on earth from MiKTeX helps to my project. Then I'm not able to minimize my MiKTeX by deleting those unused for final distribution of my project. This is the reason why I post this question